# How to easily install pywin32 with debug symbols

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2019, pywin32, debug-symbols

I am building a Python wrapper for C++ based code on Windows. The C++ code also uses COM based functionality. I am using VS2019 to compile everything. My solution structure looks like this:

- cpplibrary project
- pythonwrapper project
- python test code project

Everything works as expected when compiled in release.
I'd like to compile everything in debug mode to troubleshoot different logic issues.

But pythonwrapper project expects debug mode libs, raising:

```
LNK1104 cannot open file 'pythoncom_d.lib'
```

How can I easily install `pywin32` package (which also includes `pythoncom) with debug libraries?

I tried to clone `pywin32` and compile it as the following:

```
python setup.py build --debug
```

But no matter what I do I am getting the following error:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.2 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

I am running VS2019 with all the required additions. I also tried install just the Build Tools as described with different Windows 10 SDKs. No matter what I do, I am ending up with this error